# Javascript easy onclick example not working

Tags: javascript

My `test.jsp` file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script  type="text/javascript" src="js/test.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <a href='#' id='mylink'>click me</a>
</body>
</html>
```

My `test.js` file:

```
alert("HELLO");

var myLink = document.getElementById('mylink');

myLink.onclick = function(){

    alert("I am a pop up ! ");

}
```

When I load the `test.jsp` page the `Hello` alert appears just fine. However when I click on `click me`, nothing happens.

Comment: Works for me as a code snippet here. Try to put `var myLink = document.getElementById('mylink');` inside a `window.onload = function() {     }` block. I bet if you press F12 that it will show myLink is undefined because the DOM hasn't loaded yet.

Comment: just put script tag in the end of body tag after a tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the point your script is running, the rest of the DOM hasn't been created yet.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <a href='#' id='mylink'>click me</a>
    <script  type="text/javascript" src="js/test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Moving the script tag to the bottom is one way to fix that.

Comment: Well you shouldn't. `onload` solution is much better.

Answer (score 2):

It works fine here. Try wrapping it in an onload event listener to ensure the DOM is ready when the `document.getElementById` is called on the `mylink` element.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function()
{
  var myLink = document.getElementById('mylink');
  myLink.onclick = function() {
    alert("I am a pop up ! ");
  }
});
```

```html
<a href='#' id='mylink'>click me</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a common issue of timing on how things are loaded into the browser on your page. The browser will run scripts and load HTML as it encounters it from the top down. Your JS file is running at the very top of the page. This means, at the point of its execution, the A HREF tag doesn't exist when you create the onclick event. The big issue is that when you call this line:

```
 document.getElementById('mylink');
```

That A HREF tag doesn't yet exist, because the browser hasn't yet made it down the page to that line to load the tag into memory (again, because your JS file is at the top of the page). It's a timing issue. That function call returns null, effectively.

You need to put the event handler creation either on an body.onload event or, since you are using the jQuery library, inside a document.ready event. This delays the onclick event creation until the tag is loaded into memory and ready. For example:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
      var myLink = document.getElementById('mylink');
      myLink.onclick = function(){
          alert("I am a pop up ! ");
      }
 });
```